# Firebase update or set

Tags: javascript, firebase

After adding a post about a person to a Firebase database, I want to add the reference to the new post to the person. However the person may or may not already exist.

I have:

```
var ref = new Firebase("https://mydatabase.firebaseio.com/");
var _person = document.getElementById("Person").value;
var _remark = document.getElementById("Remark").value;

var postsRef = ref.child("remarks");
var newPostRef = postsRef.push({
    person: _person,
    remark: _remark
});

var postID = newPostRef.key();

var personRef = ref.child("person");
personRef.update({
    _person: postID
});
```

However that creates a node called `_person` in child person instead of the value of the `_person` variable. Using `set()` would overwrite an existing person.

Example:
First a node `remarks/-JlkbxAKpQs50W7r84gf` is created with child node `person/123456`

After that I want to create a node `person/123456` (only if it doesn't already exist) and than add a child node `remark/-JlkbxAKpQs50W7r84gf` to it. The post-id is automatically generated (Firebase) but the person's id is to be taken from a html form.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Depending on how your data is structured, before you `update`, you may be able to get a reference to the `person` you want.

So, if your data looks something like this:

```
{
    "remarks" : {
                   ...
                },

    "person" : {
                 "123456" : {
                                "name" : "foo",
                                ...
                                "blah" : "bar"
                            },
                 ...
               }
}
```

And `document.getElementById("Person").value` gives you `123456`, you can get the reference like:

```
var personRef = ref.child("person").child(_person);
```

Then you want to see if it exists, and if it does, update it:

```
personRef.once('value', function(snapshot) {

    if( snapshot.val() === null ) {
        /* does not exist */
    } else {
        snapshot.ref.update({"postID": postID});
    }

});
```

Comment: In your above example, I believe `ref` is a property, not a method. In other words, it should be `snapshot.ref` not `snapshot.ref()`. I'm not sure if this has changed in newer versions of Firebase, but I ran into this issue recently.

Comment: snapshot.ref() is not function, and calling snaphot.ref on root reference will return null